# Boost.Program_options fixed number of tokens

Tags: c++, boost-program-options

Boost.Program_options provides a facility to pass multiple tokens via command line arguments as follows:

```
std::vector<int> nums;    

po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "Produce help message.")
    ("nums", po::value< std::vector<int> >(&nums)->multitoken(), "Numbers.")
;

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);
po::notify(vm);
```

However, what is the preferred way of accepting only a fixed number of arguments? The only solution I could come is to manually assign values:

```
int nums[2];    

po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
desc.add_options()
    ("help", "Produce help message.")
    ("nums", "Numbers.")
;

po::variables_map vm;
po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, desc), vm);

if (vm.count("nums")) {
   // Assign nums
}
```

This feels a bit clumsy. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boost library only provides the predefined mechanisms. A quick search didn't find something with a fixed number of values. But you can create this yourself. The `po::value< std::vector<int> >(&nums)->multitoken()` is just a specialized [value_semantic](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/value_semantic.html) class. As you can see, this class offers the methods `min_tokens` and `max_tokens`, which seems to do exactly what you want. If you look at the [definition](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/boost/program_options/value_semantic.hpp) of class `typed_value` ( *this is the object that gets created, when you call `po::value< std::vector<int> >(&nums)->multitoken()`*) you can get the grasp of how the methods should be overridden.

Comment: I did see `min_tokens` and `max_tokens`, but I wasn´t certain how they were meant to be used. Thanks for pointing out the `typed_value` class. It seems like it's the way to go, even though it's not quite as easy as I had hoped it would be.

Comment: @kloffy If you are looking for an example on how to derive from that `typed_value` class, look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59761124/use-boostprogram-options-to-specify-multiple-flags